# table 1 and table 2, what join shall I use. Also if someone can explain joins will be great

Tags: mysql, sql

**table 1**

```
| Week Number | Year number | Amount | Invoices | Order |
```

**table 2**

```
| Week Number | Year Number | Forcasted Value |
```

**Desired Output Needed :**

```
| Week Number | Year number | Amount | Invoices | Order | Forcasted Value |
```

What join shall I use to get this o/p ?

Thanks!!

Comment: you should add a linking column like order_id

Comment: Hi @S.Y.K.J I will advise two things: first try not to use word `Order` in your table column. Second please do add to your question from which of two tables do you want to your output data be for columns "Week Number" and "Year number"

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word in mysql

Comment: Week Number and Year Number are same in both table 1 & 2.So how can I get the desired o/p as stated

Answer (score 0):

Start with an `inner join`:

```
select *
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     using (week_number, year_number);
```

You will lose week/year combos that are not in both tables.  For that, you would want an outer join.  However, your question does not provide enough information to specify what type of join.